# Java: Other possible forms for return statement

Tags: java, return, postfix-operator

Suppose I wish to return `tos = tos-2`, than how can the code be modified?

```
int pop() {
    System.out.print("tos   = " +tos+"  ");
    if (tos<0) {
        System.out.println("Stack limit reached .. UNDERFLOW");
        return 0;}
    else {
        return stck[tos--]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `else { tos-=2 return stck[tos]; }`

Comment: What do you exactly want to return?

Comment: tos-=2; return stck[]tos; // this is not working

Comment: Like Mureinik mentioned, using the postfix operator within an expression is asking for trouble.

Comment: Keep the code clear and readable is important. Usually is better to have some extra lines of code instead of some hard to read and error prone lines

Comment: Lol, didnt read the response of others. same solutions. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have an unary "decrement by two" operator, so you'll have to split it to two lines:

```
tos -= 2;
return stck[tos + 2];
```

Or use a temp value for readability:

```
tos -= 2;
int returnIndex = tos + 2;
return stck[returnIndex];
```

Comment: This returns the wrong thing if using post increment

Comment: @akxlr That's why I hate postfix operators... fixed. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the array position prior to the change of `tos` (similar to what `return stck[tos--]` would do) :

```
tos-=2;
return stck[tos+2];
```

Otherwise,

```
tos-=2;
return stck[tos];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int pop(){
    System.out.print("tos   = " +tos+"  ");
    if (tos<0) {
        System.out.println("Stack limit reached .. UNDERFLOW");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        tos = tos-2;
        return stck[tos];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a plain-English explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int pop(){

    System.out.print("tos   = " +tos+"  ");
    if (tos<0) {
        System.out.println("Stack limit reached .. UNDERFLOW");
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        tos -=2;
        return stck[tos];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stop using postfix. :D

```
int pop() {
        int tos = 2;//3

        System.out.print("tos   = " + tos + "  ");
        if (tos < 0) {
            System.out.println("Stack limit reached .. UNDERFLOW");
            return 0;
        } 

        return stck[tos-=2];
    }
```